# Remove shipping form custom attribute from address in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, forms

I followed the first steps of this documentation (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html) to add a new input field (date of birth) to the shipping address form in checkout. Here is my relevant code in a plugin class:

```
    <?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Vendor\Module\Helper\Data;

class AddDob
{

    private $_helper;


    function __construct(
        Data $helper
    )
    {
        $this->_helper = $helper;
    }


    public function afterProcess($subject, $jsLayout)
    {
        if (!$this->_helper->isEnabled()) return $jsLayout;

        $customAttributeCode = 'dob';

        $customField = [
            'component' => 'Vendor_Module/js/form/element/dob',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                'customEntry' => null,
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'Vendor_Module/form/element/dob'
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.'.$customAttributeCode,
            'label' => __('Date of birth'),
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'sortOrder' => $this->_helper->getSortOrder(),
            'options' => [],
            'filterBy' => null,
            'customEntry' => null,
            'visible' => true,
        ];

        if ($this->_helper->isRequired()) {
            $customField['validation']['required-entry'] = true;
        }

        if ($this->_helper->tooltipIsEnabled()) {
            $customField['config']['tooltip'] = [
                'description' => $this->_helper->tooltipGetContent()
            ];
        }

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$customAttributeCode] = $customField;

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

I also implemented the plugin class via di.xml. So it works basically as you can see here:
[image]

However when I proceed to the billing form, I see two new rows in the address, one says "**dob**" (*which is the name of my date of birth input field*) and the other one displays its value, as you can see here:
[image]

But I do not want them to appear in the address. **How can I get rid of it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the following file:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/details.html

Following code is responsible for rendering custom attributes

```
<each args="data: currentBillingAddress().customAttributes, as: 'element'">
    <each args="data: Object.keys(element), as: 'attribute'">
        <if args="typeof element[attribute] === 'object'">
            <if args="element[attribute].label">
                <text args="element[attribute].label"/>
            </if>
            <ifnot args="element[attribute].label">
                <if args="element[attribute].value">
                    <text args="element[attribute].value"/>
                </if>
            </ifnot>
        </if>
        <if args="typeof element[attribute] === 'string'">
            <text args="element[attribute]"/>
        </if><br/>
    </each>
</each>
```

So overwrite this template and remove this code section.